# Javascript code is working in Firefox but not in IE or Safari

Tags: javascript

The following code is working with Firefox, but neither with IE 10 nor with Safari:

```
function showids(id) { //new
   divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
   for ( var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++ ) {
    if(divs[i].id.startsWith('id1')) {
        alert(divs[i].id);
        if(divs[i].id.startsWith('id1'+id))
            divs[i].className='one';
        else {
            divs[i].className='two';
            alert('-'+divs[i].id);
        }
      }
     }
 }
```

Does anybody know the reason?

Comment: maybe `startsWith` is not supported, check console for errors

Comment: `String.prototype.startsWith()` is a new function from ECMAScript 6. You will need to polyfill for most browsers.

Comment: Or use a different method - like a regex

Comment: As @user2182349 says, you can use a different function: `if (divs[i].id.indexOf('id1') === 0) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

`startsWith` isn't supported in IE or Safari. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith

Comment: Thanks. This site gave the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the line

```
if(divs[i].id.startsWith('id1')) {
```

for the follow line, using an alternative for *startsWith*

```
if(divs[i].id.indexOf('id1')==0) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this Code from developer.mozzilla.org:

```
if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
  String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
    position = position || 0;
    return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
  };
}
```

Now my Code is Working.
Thanks to all